# copy and rename files 2 directory up

Tags: bash, rename, file-copy, macintosh

I am trying to copy multiple files named "F3.bam" two level of directories to up and then rename these files with the name of the sub-directory after copy.

For example:

```
/samples/mydata1/RUN1/ID_date/PCR2/TIME1/F3.bam
/samples/mydata2/RUN1/ID2_date4/PCR2/TIME7/F3.bam
/samples/mydataxxx/RUN1/IDxxx_datexxx/PCR2/TIMExxx/F3.bam
```

Expected results:

#### 1. The files are first copied two directories level up:

```
/samples/mydata1/RUN1/ID_date/F3.bam
/samples/mydata2/RUN1/ID2_date4/F3.bam
/samples/mydataxxx/RUN1/IDxxx_datexxx/F3.bam
```

#### 2. The files are renamed according to the name of the current sub-directory:

```
/samples/mydata1/RUN1/ID_date/ID_date_F3.bam
/samples/mydata2/RUN1/ID2_date4/ID2_date4_F3.bam
/samples/mydataxxx/RUN1/IDxxx_datexxx/IDxxx_datexxx_F3.bam
```

Ideally a bash loop would be great (working on a Mac).

Answer (score 1):

Here's the TLDR version of my solution: you can use the `dirname` and `basename` commands along with process substitution in order to construct the target path for your copy command.

A longer explanation follows.

---

Here is a (super verbose) script that does roughly what you want using a Bash loop:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# copy_and_rename.bash
#
#   Copy multiple files 2 folders up and rename these files
#   to contain their parent directory as a prefix.
#

# Set internal field separator to handle spaces in file names
IFS=$'\n'

# Iterate over the list of file paths
for _file_path in $@; do

    # Get the file name
    _file_name="$(basename ${_file_path})"

    echo "${_file_name}"

    # Get the path to the target directory (two levels above the file)
    _target_directory_path=$(dirname $(dirname ${_file_path}))

    echo "${_target_directory_path}"

    # Get the parent directory of the target directory
    _parent_directory_path=$(dirname ${_target_directory_path})

    echo "${_parent_directory_path}"

    # Get the name of the parent directory
    _parent_directory_name=$(basename ${_parent_directory_path})

    echo "${_parent_directory_name}"

    # Construct the new file path
    _new_file_path="${_target_directory_path}/${_parent_directory_name}_${_file_name}"

    echo "${_new_file_path}"

    # Copy and rename the file
    echo "cp -i \"${_file_path}\" \"${_new_file_path}\""
    cp -i "${_file_path}" "${_new_file_path}"
    echo
done
```

You can obviously compress this a lot, but I kept it this way for explanatory value.

Here is what the preceding script looks like without any comments or superfluous variables or `echo` statements:

```bsh
for _file_path in $@; do
    cp -i "${_file_path}" \
    "$(dirname $(dirname ${_file_path}))/$(basename $(dirname $(dirname $(dirname ${_file_path}))))_$(basename ${_file_path})"
done
```

It's very fragile and doesn't do much in the way of error-handling. I also left in some `echo` statements for debugging so you see what it's doing and can sanity-check it when you run it for the first time.

To test it I created your files by using the following script, which I include here in case you find it useful for further testing:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# create_test_files.bash

# Set internal field separator to handle spaces in file names
IFS=$'\n'

# Choose an prefix for the file paths
_prefix="/tmp"

# Create array of sample files
_sample_files=(
    "/samples/mydata1/RUN1/ID_date/PCR2/TIME1/F3.bam"
    "/samples/mydata2/RUN1/ID2_date4/PCR2/TIME7/F3.bam"
    "/samples/mydataxxx/RUN1/IDxxx_datexxx/PCR2/TIMExxx/F3.bam"
)

# Create directories and files
for _file in "${_sample_files[@]}"; do

    # Add the prefix to the path
    _path="${_prefix}${_file}"

    # Create parent directory
    mkdir -p "$(dirname ${_path})"

    # Create file
    touch "${_path}"
done
```

I check that the files were created properly by using the `find` command:

```bsh
$ find /tmp/samples -type f

/tmp/samples/mydata1/RUN1/ID_date/PCR2/TIME1/F3.bam
/tmp/samples/mydata2/RUN1/ID2_date4/PCR2/TIME7/F3.bam
/tmp/samples/mydataxxx/RUN1/IDxxx_datexxx/PCR2/TIMExxx/F3.bam
```

Then I invoke the script like this:

```bsh
bash copy_and_rename.bash \
/tmp/samples/mydata1/RUN1/ID_date/PCR2/TIME1/F3.bam \
/tmp/samples/mydata2/RUN1/ID2_date4/PCR2/TIME7/F3.bam \
/tmp/samples/mydataxxx/RUN1/IDxxx_datexxx/PCR2/TIMExxx/F3.bam
```

And then I check that the script worked by using `find` again:

```bsh
$ find /tmp/samples -type f

/tmp/samples/mydata1/RUN1/ID_date/PCR2/ID_date_F3.bam
/tmp/samples/mydata1/RUN1/ID_date/PCR2/TIME1/F3.bam
/tmp/samples/mydata2/RUN1/ID2_date4/PCR2/ID2_date4_F3.bam
/tmp/samples/mydata2/RUN1/ID2_date4/PCR2/TIME7/F3.bam
/tmp/samples/mydataxxx/RUN1/IDxxx_datexxx/PCR2/IDxxx_datexxx_F3.bam
/tmp/samples/mydataxxx/RUN1/IDxxx_datexxx/PCR2/TIMExxx/F3.bam
```

Finally, I delete all of the test files, also using `find`:

```bsh
find /tmp/samples -type f -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: That looks very promising! I will give it a try asap and keep you posted

Answer (score 1):

This version uses only bash parameter substitution to slice and dice paths. Pass it one or more absolute file paths:

```
#!/bin/env bash
for path; do
    dir="${path%/*}"
    dest="${dir%/*/*}"
    cp "$path" "${dest}/${dest##*/}_${path##*/}"
done
```

Here is an expanded version. This one also accepts relative paths and the number of parent dirs to traverse is tunable:

```
#!/bin/env bash

# Each param for this script is the path of a file. It
# accepts relative paths if you have appropriate tool to
# robustly determine absolute paths (not trivial). Here
# we're using GNU 'realpath' tool.
#
# Usage: copy2up filepath1 [filepath2...]

# for converting relative paths to absolute
# if it's missing replace realpath with available tool
# (or just always use absolute path arguments)
pathtool=realpath

# directory levels upwards to copy files
levels=2

# iterate over each parameter
for path; do
    if [[ ! $path =~ ^/ ]]; then
        # convert relative to absolute
        path="$($pathtool $path)"
    fi
    file="${path##*/}"
    dir="${path%/*}"

    dest=$dir
    # chdir upwards 'levels' times to destination
    for (( i=0; i<$levels; i++ )); do
        dest="${dest%/*}"
    done

    # to be prepended to original filename
    destpfx="${dest##*/}"

    newpath="${dest}/${destpfx}_${file}"
    cp "$path" "$newpath"
done
```

As for your specific use case, you could run this with `find` if that's how you are locating your 'F3.bam' files. For example:

```
find /some/path -name F3.bam -exec copy2up.sh {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `find` and [`shell (POSIX sh/bash/Korn/zsh) parameter substitution expansion`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) as following.

```bsh
find . -type f -name "F3.bam" -execdir sh -c '
    trgt="${PWD%/*/*}"; echo cp -v "$1" "${trgt}/${trgt##*/}_${1#./}" ' _ '{}' \;
```

**Explanations:**:

We are looking for the files only matching `F3.bam` and with `-execdir` here, `find` is changing the current directory to the directory where file `F3.bam` found then execute the `sh -c ' ... '` within that directory itself.

With `trgt="${PWD%/*/*}"` "cut-up-to-first-suffix": We are getting ride of the *filename* itself and two level of its sub-directories in `/samples/mydata1/RUN1/ID_date**/PCR2/TIME1**` (**bold** part that matches `/*/*` suffix will remove) and assign to variable `trgt`. So `trgt` is now set to `/samples/mydata1/RUN1/ID_date` for first file.

The `"$1"` is relative *filepath* `./filename` to the current `$PWD`.

In `${trgt##*/}_` "cut-up-to-last-prefix": We used `trgt` variable value to get the sub-directory name which should pre-pend to the filename, So this will return only `ID_date`, `ID2_date4` or `IDxxx_datexxx`, etc (removing everything until last slash `/` seen) and add a underscore `_`.

This `${1#./}` removes point-slash `./` from the relative `./filepath`.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest `dirname` as often as you like:

```
set /samples/mydata1/RUN1/ID_date/PCR2/TIME1/F3.bam \
/samples/mydata2/RUN1/ID2_date4/PCR2/TIME7/F3.bam \
/samples/mydataxxx/RUN1/IDxxx_datexxx/PCR2/TIMExxx/F3.bam

for bam; do
  dir="$(dirname "$(dirname "$(dirname "$bam")")")"
  mv "$bam" "$dir"/"$(basename "$dir")"_"$(basename "$bam")"
done
```